# Error when create release using gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, azure-pipelines, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, cicd

I tried to create a release using gitlab-ci and got error like this, how to fix it

```
time="2022-01-11T08:19:58Z" level=info msg="Creating Release..." cli=release-cli command=create name=v0.0.28 project-id=3 ref=cb9b21c941d56d5ac592fc5d28610c3dc9981b9d server-url="http://example.com" tag-name=v0.0.28 version=0.10.0 time="2022-`01-11T08:19:58Z" level=fatal msg="run app" cli=release-cli error="failed to create release: failed to decode response: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type gitlab.CreateReleaseResponse" version=0.10.0`
```